# Authenticating users with okta in vue + typescript app - successful login but user is never authenticated

Tags: typescript, vue.js, okta

I have followed the quick setup guide with okta to get it running with my vue + typescript app. I have the routes protected and integrated the okta login functionality. However, upon successful login, when I call Auth.isAuthenticated() I always get false even though login was successful. This is preventing me from displaying the protected routes. based on the documentation, the Auth.handleCallback() function is supposed to parse the returned data from okta and properly set the tokens in local storage, but that isn't happening either as the okta-token-storage is always empty.

I have searched the internet for two days now with no luck - I am hoping it is something super simple that I am missing. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my router.ts file where I setup the Auth module:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';
import Auth from '@okta/okta-vue';
import Profile from './views/Profile.vue'

Vue.use(Auth, {
  issuer: "{myDomainIsHere}",
  client_id: "{myIdIsHere}",
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback',
  authorizeUrl: "{myDomain}/oauth2/default/v1/authorize",
  userinfoUrl: "{myDomain}/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo",
  scope: 'openid profile email'
});

let router = new Router({

  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/my-profile',
      name: 'user-profile',
      component: Profile,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/implicit/callback',
      component: Auth.handleCallback(),
    },
  ]
});

router.beforeEach(Vue.prototype.$auth.authRedirectGuard());
export default router;
```

and here is my navigation component where this gets checked:

```
import {Vue, Component, Watch} from "vue-property-decorator";
    @Component
    export default class Navigation extends Vue {
        private authenticated:boolean = false;

        private created() {
            this.isUserAuthenticated();
        }
        @Watch('$route')
        private async isUserAuthenticated(){
            this.authenticated = await Vue.prototype.$auth.isAuthenticated();
            console.log(this.authenticated);
        }
        private async logout(){
            await Vue.prototype.$auth.logout();
            await this.isUserAuthenticated();
            this.$router.push({path: '/'});
        }

    }
```

When I console.log the instance variable "this.authenticated" I get false every time the route changes - even though I successfully logged in through the okta service

Comment: You might try using our OktaDev Schematics project. It makes it much easier to integrate Vue with Okta and includes support for JavaScript and TypeScript. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@oktadev/schematics#vue.

Comment: Can you provide some context around "makes it much easier"? I'd like to know how to adjust my own app to produce the desired behavior. I will check out your project, though.

Comment: So I set up a brand new project and the only thing I changed was setting history mode to true on vue-router. I am pretty new to the front-end world so if someone could give a detailed explanation as to why that fixed my issue that would be awesome! From what I read it makes sense that the uri was not being parsed correctly in regular (hash) mode, but still would like better understanding.